# Why was this flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging, answers, answer-quality

The [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/147697/70236) in question consists of a wall of texts which, to my inspection, does not contain an answer to the original question. I flagged it as *not an answer*, yet my flag was disputed.

So my question is 1a) why was it disputed (i.e. is it an actual answer?) 1b) what actually constitutes a "not an answer"?

Comment: Ouch. I just tried to edit that wall of text. Hopefully it's a little better now.

Comment: @Mithrandir - You're doing God's work, but that answer is beyond redemption.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer since your main question is "why" rather than "who", but **your flag was handled by the community through the review queues** rather than by a moderator. You [can see](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/96126) that two users voted to delete the post while two voted that it looks OK.

Comment: @Randal'Thor  -  I see, thank you. I'll try to be more moderate with flags next time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Arguably this lump of text

> "*if like I said elves have dominant traits that would have a higher
>   chance to pass through each generation instead of the human ones then
>   technically Aragon would still be more elf."*

answers the question asked.

---

'[Not an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)' only really applies to answers that have little or no bearing on the question asked, for example if it's been posted to the wrong question.

Comment: That link says `not even a partial answer to the actual question`. Doesn't this one qualify?

Comment: @Gallifreian - If they'd solely posted the sentence above (with a bit of elaboration) it would make a solid answer.

Comment: Looks like he’s floating a hypothesis (out of thin air) and then drawing a conclusion from it. Suppose somebody asks, “Where can I get some [apples](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/300663)?” and somebody answers, “Well, if apple seeds were planted in Alaska, and the climate there is conducive to apple-growing, then you might be able to find apples in Alaska.”  That’s a syllogism where the inputs are pure speculation (and the second one is probably false).  Is that an answer? If a question asks yes or no, and an answer says, “Maybe” and presents some discussion, is that an answer?

Comment: @PeregrineRook - Yes, that would be a perfectly good example of an answer that's worthy of downvote, but not closure as "not an answer".

Comment: Wow.  Let me go flooding the site with "maybe" answers; as long as my downvote/upvote ratio is less than 5, I'll gain rep!   :-)   ⁠

Comment: @PeregrineRook - Intentionally posting crap answers may earn you some rep, but it'll also earn you an unsavoury reputation.